# Strange C++ compilation error with header file due to makefile setting?

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I have the following defined in the header file:

```
some function ...
            if (table2[i] != ""){
                new_table2[hash2(table2[i])] = table2[i];       
                table2[i] = "";
                }       
            // std::cout << " first i : " << i  << "\n";
        }


        for (int i=0; i < 150; ++i){
            if (new_table1[i] != "" && !try_insert(new_table1[i])){
                std::cout << " bad rehash : " << i << " " << new_table1[i]  << "\n"; 
                rehash();
            }
        }
```

Makefile looks like this:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -O3.
DEPS = somehash.h hashfunctions.h 
OBJ = main.o

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

main: $(OBJ)
    g++ -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)


.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f *.o main
```

After I do make clean, make, and ./main, "first i" is still printed even though it is commented out. When I comment out " bad rehash ", then both of them are not printed. It seems the compiler did some auto optimization that causes this to be cached? How can I fix it?

Edit: I opened the file in another editor (was using Sublime), and the problem went away. It seem the problem is sublime.

Comment: The compiler is *not* uncommenting code for you! You appear to have a dot after `-O3` in your Makefile, what's up with that? You need to provide a reproducible example. What you're suggesting is nonsensical at the moment.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: I'm working in a mac.

Comment: Could it be that you're linking with a library or something similar which has the "old" version of the code compiled into it?

Comment: Which header file is that in? Are you sure the object file with that code got recompiled after you commented the line with `first i` out? Can you reproduce this problem now?

Comment: Is your header compiled to a pre-compiled header?

Comment: The main.cpp and header files are in the same directory as makefile. No pre-compiled header. No other library in the same folder or subfolder. I was using sublime text. I moved the entire directory to another directory, opened

Comment: I was using sublime text. I moved the entire directory to another directory, opened using Textwrangler, then the problem went away. It seems the problem may be sublime, first time experiencing this.